# How to convert some character into numeric in php?

Tags: php

I need help to change a character in php.
I got some code from the web:

```
char dest='a';
int conv=(int)dest;
```

Can I use this code to convert a character into numeric? Or do you have any ideas?
I just want to show the result as a decimal number:

```
if null == 0
if A == 1
```

Comment: What number do you want? The ascii code?

Comment: No you can't use that code - it isn't php.

Comment: i'm just need standard number like 0,1,2,3...

Comment: "just want to show result as decimal number" **What number?!** A letter is not a number. You need to define how a letter would correspond to a number. Should 'A' correspond to 1? Do you want the ASCII code where 'A' corresponds to 65?

Comment: @deceze: i want if "null == 0" and if i type "A == 1".

Comment: I understand less each time you edit your question.

Comment: Oh come on, it's finally rather cleared up. :) a-z/A-Z (just assuming case doesn't matter) should be converted to 1-26, and `null`/`false` values to 0.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use [**ord()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) to return the ascii value. Subtract 96 to return a number where a=1, b=2....

Upper and lower case letters have different ASCII values, so if you want to handle them the same, you can use [**strtolower()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) to convert upper case to lower case.

To handle the `NULL` case, simply use `if($dest)`. This will be true if `$dest` is something other than `NULL` or `0`.

PHP is a loosely typed language, so there is no need to declare the types. So `char dest='a';` is incorrect. Variables have `$` prefix in PHP and no type declaration, so it should be `$dest = 'a';`.

[**Live Example**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/wnfhnX)

```
<?php

    function toNumber($dest)
    {
        if ($dest)
            return ord(strtolower($dest)) - 96;
        else
            return 0;
    }

      // Let's test the function...        
    echo toNumber(NULL) . " ";
    echo toNumber('a') . " ";
    echo toNumber('B') . " ";
    echo toNumber('c');

      // Output is:
      // 0 1 2 3
?>
```

PS:
[You can look at the ASCII values here](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: Doesn't handle upper case correctly, but seems to be on the right track.

Comment: @deceze - That's because upper and lower have different ASCII values. I edited the answer so that upper case is handled the same way as lower case.

Comment: how if null? i want if null == 0

Comment: @klox - I edited the answer so that `toNumber` uses an `if ... else ...` statement to hand the `NULL` & `0` cases. You can also use `is_null()` to check for only null, but I think `if($dest)` works better in this case.

Comment: used this answer to as part of an answer to a different question of my own found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566638/phpexcel-how-to-get-only-1-cell-value/22566639)

Answer (score 3):

It does indeed work as  in the sample, except that you should be using php syntax (and as a sidenote: the language that code you found most probably was, it did not do the same thing).

So:

```
$in = "123";
$out = (int)$in;
```

Afterwards the following will be true:

```
$out === 123
```

Comment: is this not reversed? I wish if null mean zero and if I type A the result is 1

Comment: @Brendan Long: I interpreted `i'm just need standard number like 0,1,2,3` as him saying he wanted this, but as you say it's not clear. I added a result to my answer so it's clear what this does.

Answer (score 2):

So, if you need the ASCII code you will need to do:

```
$dest = 'a';
$conv = ord($dest);
```

If you want something like:

```
a == 1
b == 2
.
.
.
```

you should do:

```
$dest = 'a';
$conv = ord($dest)-96;
```

For more info on the ASCII codes: http://www.asciitable.com/

And for the function ord: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to answer because it's not a real question but just a little bit of it.
But if you ask.
It seems you need some translation table, that defines links between letters and numbers

```
A -> 2
B -> 3
C -> 4
S -> 1
```

or whatever.
You can achieve this by using an array, where keys would be these letters and values - desired numbers.

```
$defects_arr = array(
    'A' -> 2,
    'B' -> 3,
    'C' -> 4'
    'S' -> 1
};
```

Thus, you can convert these letters to numbers

```
$letter = 'A';
$number = $defects_arr($letter);
echo $number; // outputs 1
```

But it still seems is not what you want.
Do these defect types have any verbose equivalents? If so, why not to use them instead of letters?

Telling the whole story instead of little bit of it will help you to avoid mistakes and will save a ton of time, both yours and those who to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Out of this question, if you are looking for convert `RT0005` to `5`

```
$max = 'RT0005';
return base_convert($max,10,10);
// return 5
```